# Java EE, casting Entity to Extended one!

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, casting, entity

Goodmorning.
I have two entitis, User and User1 (which extends User with `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)`, adding some extra information like email, phonenumber and so on... attributes not required for the entity User).

Now... `User user` is already persisted. 
I would like, in future, to be able to cast this user, providing that extra data, doing something like this:

```
User1 user1 = (User1)user;
user1.setEmail("email@email.com");
```

I've tried this solution, but of course... it doesn't work!
(Casting Exception Returned).

Any idea? Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate as JPA provider? Most providers will instantiate the right entity when they are part of a polimorphic inheritance relationship. If the user you are retrieving is indeed a User1 the downcast should succeed. Is the user in question really a User1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting in Java doesn't work that way. You can only cast to Objects you actually extend from.

What you *could* do is provide a Copy Constructor in your extended Entity:

```
public ExtendedUser(BasicUser user){
    this.setFoo(user.getFoo());
    this.setBar(user.getBar());
}
```

But there's no way to cast something into something it doesn't extend. That's called type safety and is one of the most important aspects of Java.

**Reference:**

- Java Language Specification: [5.1.6 Narrowing Reference
  Conversions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#25379)

Comment: Thank you! I've tried that solution, but... there is something wrong. It's creating a new record on User, too.. with a new id, and this new record is correctly extended. I would like to keep the user with the original id, and just adding extra data!

Comment: @Mauro maybe you should change your design and keep your extended data in another entity which you associate with a `@OneToOne(optional)` reference.

Comment: That means I have to remove the extends? I'm completelly lost. I'm sorry for my questions, I'm a JEE newbie.

Comment: @Mauro either remove the extends (replace inheritance with aggregation) or instantiate the user as `new ExtendedUser()` in the first place, yes.

Comment: @Mauro which did you choose?  new ExtendedUser() or aggregation?